# Rasberry pi: i2c error display all connection

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

when i work with rasberry i got this error and the connection to my i2c pin has problem. Is there any way to solve it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9U7V.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please give us an actual description of the problem/error rather than an image.

Comment: Adding to @QWERTYL's comment, this is worth a read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: ah i'm a new user and i don't know this, i will consider next time, sorry so much